# How to perform a left join when joined field is null or 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have two tables having a 1-to-many relation:  `WorkOrder` 1 - * `Service`

They have a relation via a field: `ServiceID`

Due to some legacy reasons, there are some `WorkOrder`  does not have any `Service`, but its `ServiceID` field is saved as 0

---

Now I want to select all `WorkOrders` *iff*

There is a matching `Service` OR `WorkOrder`'s `ServiceID` = 0

Without the `ServiceID = 0` requirement it should be a normal left join:

```
 var result = from wo in WorkOrderQuery
              join j in JobQuery on ... // join some other tables
              join s in ServiceQuery on wo.ServiceID equals s.ServiceID into gg
              from g in gg.DefaultIfEmpty()
              select new 
              {
                 ServiceCode = g == null? "" : g.Code,
                 WorkOrderID = wo.WorkOrderID,
              };
```

But I have no idea when this requirement is added. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Can't you simply update the wrong records? Something like: `update workorder set serviceid  = null where serviceid=0;`

Comment: No, I would do it if I can but that's a corporate decision that they should remain unchanged

Comment: @shole - if you have a foreign key's value that doesn't really map to an actual record in the other table -> it isn't a foreign key...

Comment: @GiladGreen Thanks! you are right, updated question that use a more suitable term...

Comment: It has to be a better way, but as a quick solution, if you cannot change the records, you can create a view, and simple use the view instead of the original table to do a normal `left join`: `create view v_workorderquery as select case when serviceid = 0 then NULL else serviceid, [other_columns] from workorderquery`

Comment: I guess you don't have a `Service` record with `Id = 0`. Then the left outer join should work the way it is.

Comment: @shole - can you please show some sample data and what you want to get?

Comment: @GiladGreen I have a peek on your updated answer, I think you are getting correct idea :)   So far for my test it works well, please re-open it so that I can accept it :)

Comment: @shole - did so :) I just got confused with what you actually wanted to output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly sure that I've understood but try this:

```
var result = (from wo in WorkOrderQuery
              join s in ServiceQuery on wo.ServiceID equals s.ServiceID into g
              from s in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
              where wo.ServiceID == 0 || s != null
              select new 
              {
                  ServiceCode = s?.Code ?? string.Empty,
                  WorkOrderID = wo.WorkOrderID
              }).ToList();
```

Tested on this data:

```
List<dynamic> WorkOrderQuery = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { WorkOrderID = 1, ServiceID = 1 },
    new { WorkOrderID = 2, ServiceID = 2 },
    new { WorkOrderID = 3, ServiceID = 0 }
};

List<dynamic> ServiceQuery = new List<dynamic>
{
    new { ServiceID  = 1, Code = "a" }
};
```

And getting `WorkOrderID` 1,3

Comment: Maybe i'm wrong, but a record in WorkOrderQuery with serviceid=0, will match all the records on servicequery, because the first condition, and he wants no matching on that case. So `s` will never be null for that records with that code. Maybe the assignement should be `ServiceCode = wo.ServiceId == null || wo.ServiceId == 0 ? string.empty : ......`

Comment: Maybe @Rumpelstinsk is right. I tried this and seems it selects too many records...Thanks for the quick answer though.

Comment: Thanks...and I like the C# 6.0 syntax! (But to others like me who do not have it, just do the old school  null checking)

Comment: @shole - haha no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

> Without the ServiceID = 0 requirement it should be a normal left join

By definition `left outer join` incudes **every** record from the left side regardless of whether there is a matching right side record.

Since your `WorkOrder` is at the left side of the join, you should a use normal left join regardless of your "new requirement".